# Jupyter notebook is not opening anaconda 3 with python 3.7

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda3 on my windows 10 with python 3.7, but when I open jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator or from start menu it is not opening, from anaconda prompt it is showing this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jsonschema._format import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py", line 240, in <module>
    @_checks_drafts(draft7="idn-hostname", raises=idna.IDNAError)
AttributeError: module 'idna' has no attribute 'IDNAError'
```

The install directory is "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"

Comment: Why did you change the *default* installation options?

Comment: How exactly did you install Anaconda? Can you provide some information on the version, your environment, etc?

Comment: I didn't change the default directory i just installed for all users and its default directory is programData,

Comment: I downloaded the anaconda fron their official site windows 64bit graphic installer, python 3.7 version anaconda 2020 64 bit, at first i couldn't open anaconda navigator or prompt, then I added the environment variables, PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME to the anaconda directory then navigator and prompt started working. Spyder is also working fine but i cannot open jupyter or jupyter lab

Answer (score 4):

The easy way is to install idna by running the command below.

`$pip install idna`

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the above step did not solve the problem for me as idna was already installed.
I had to uninstall and reinstall idna following below commands.

- pip uninstall idna
- pip install idna

However,I got below prompts asking to install boto3.

- Installing collected packages: idna
- ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
- openimages 0.0.1 requires boto3, which is not installed.
- cvdata 0.0.3 requires boto3, which is not installed.  apache-beam 2.31.0 requires numpy<1.21.0,>=1.14.3, but you have numpy 1.22.4 which is
  incompatible.
- apache-beam 2.31.0 requires
  typing-extensions<3.8.0,>=3.7.0, but you have typing-extensions
  4.3.0    which is incompatible.

I did install boto3 using

1. pip install boto3

Now I am not getting idna error anymore.